# C Program not ending after inputting string?

Tags: c, linux

I am completing a programming exercise and when my program is run, it never executes anything past the input line and never terminates.  No errors or warnings are coming up so I'm not sure what is wrong.  Any help would be great.

This is the assignment: 
Write a function that asks the user to input a telephone number as a string containing a threedigit area code, followed by a seven-digit number. Any other characters will be ignored, and only
the first 10 digits will be considered. Assume that the string has at most 200characters.
If the user does not provide at least 10 digits, an error message should be printed out.
It should report the telephone number in the format (123) 456-7890. Note that the user may
choose any input format, yet the program should maintain a consistent output format.
The function should be called phone_fmt. Your executable will be called phone. The function
and main should be in the files phone_fmt.c, phone_fmt.h and phone.c, respectively.

This is my code for **phone.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "phone_fmt.h"



int main(){
        char numStr[200];
        char phoneNum[14];
        int i=0;
        printf("Enter phone number string up to 200 characters: \n ");
        scanf("%s", numStr);
        if(strlen(numStr)<10){
                printf("Invalid.  Entry must be at least 10 characters.\n");
                exit(1);
        }

        while(numStr[i] != '\0' && i<10){

                if(numStr[i]>'0' &&  numStr[i]<'9')
                        break;
                i++;

        }
        if(i > 10){

                printf("Invalid.  Not enough digits to complete phone number.\n");
                exit(1);

        }

        phone_fmt(numStr, phoneNum);
        printf("Phone number: %s \n", phoneNum);
        return 0;
}
```

code for **phone_fmt.c**

```
#include "phone_fmt.h"


void phone_fmt(char *numStr, char *phoneNum){
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int c=0;
        while(numStr[i] != '\0' && c < 10){
                if(j==0){
                        phoneNum[j]='(';
                        j++;
                }
            else if(j==4){
                    phoneNum[j]=')';
                    j++;
            }

            else if(j==8){
                    phoneNum[j]='-';
                    j++;
            }
            if(numStr[i] >= '0' && numStr[i] <= '9'){
                    phoneNum[j]=numStr[i];
                    j++;
            }


       }
}
```

code for **phone_fmt.h**

```
#include<stdio.h>

void phone_fmt(char *numStr, char *phoneNum);
```

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Comment: The `while` loop in `phone_fmt` depends on `i` and `c`. But nothing in the body of the loop changes `i` or `c`.

Comment: @user3386109 is right, looks like an infinite loop.

Comment: regarding: `scanf("%s", numStr);`  1)  always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  Any returned value other than the number of input format specifiers in the first parameter means an error occurred.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]' always include a MAX characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those specifiers always append a NUL byte to the input

Comment: in file: `phone_fmt.h` the statement: 1) `#include <stdio.h` should be removed.  Do not include header files inside a header file unless that header file needs the contents of the included header file.   2)  always use 'include guards' when writing a header file.  Similar to: `#ifndef PHONE_FMT_H  newline  #define PHONE_FMT_H  newline ... #endif // PHONE_FMT_H`

Comment: Regarding; `if(i > 10){

                printf("Invalid.  Not enough digits to complete phone number.\n");
                exit(1);`  if the number of digits is greater than 10, then there is enough digits.  Suggest reversing that 'if' condition.

Comment: the assignment states that the input can be in any format, so checking for 10 characters is not sufficient.  I.E. what if the input is: `(123) 456-7890`  That is way more than 10 characters and still meets the criteria of the problem

Comment: Off by 1.  `char numStr[200]; ... 
        scanf("%s", numStr);` is one too small for "Assume that the string has at most 200characters.".  Suggest `char numStr[200 + 1]; ... 
        scanf("%200s", numStr);`

Comment: When you write code, it's a goo idea to start with something simple that works perfectly, then build up. Bugs are much easier to catch that way. In this case, a program that accepts a couple of `char` or `int` values would have been a good intermediate step.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your logic, you need to create a char or int array to hold your 10 phone digit number as your first parameter in phone_fmt() function. The worked code is following.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void phone_fmt(int *digits, char *phoneNum){

    sprintf(phoneNum, "(%d%d%d) %d%d%d-%d%d%d%d",   digits[0],
                                                    digits[1],
                                                    digits[2],
                                                    digits[3],
                                                    digits[4],
                                                    digits[5],
                                                    digits[6],
                                                    digits[7],
                                                    digits[8],
                                                    digits[9]);
}

int main(){

        char output[20];
        int digits[10];
        char c;
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        printf("Enter phone number string up to 200 characters: \n ");

        while( (c = getchar()) != '\n'  && i < 10 ){

                if( (c >= '0' && c <= '9') ){
                    digits[i++] = (int)(c - '0');
                }
                ++j;
        }

        if( j < 10 || j > 200 ){
                printf("Invalid.  Entry must be at least 10 characters and less then 200 characters.\n");
                return -1;
        }
        if(i < 10){
                printf("Invalid.  Not enough digits to complete phone number.\n");
                return -1;
        }

        phone_fmt(digits, output);
        printf("Phone number: %s \n", output);

        return 0;
}
```